# Shape file and Netcdf file in R: Error extent does not overlap

Tags: r, raster, shapefile

I have climatic data for the whole world in a netcdf file, and a shape file for UK. I want to extract climatic variables only for the UK region. I have this code and I get an error of not overlapping.

```
# Load the required libraries
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(raster)
library(ncdf4)
library(rgdal)

#Read the shapefile
uk_shapefile <- st_read("/Users/macbook/Dropbox/nc_file/Great_Britain_shapefile/gb_1km.shp")

# Extract the bounding box of the UK shapefile
uk_bbox <- st_bbox(uk_shapefile)

# Read the netCDF file
netcdf_file <- "/Users/macbook/Dropbox/nc_file/data2.nc"
nc_data <- nc_open(netcdf_file)

# Extract the variables you need from the netCDF file
variable_data <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "t2m")

# Get the longitude and latitude dimensions from the netCDF file
lon <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "longitude")
lat <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "latitude")

# Convert variable_data to a matrix
variable_matrix <- as.matrix(variable_data)

# Create a raster layer from the extracted variable data
raster_data <- raster(variable_matrix, xmn = min(lon), xmx = max(lon), ymn = min(lat), ymx = max(lat))

# Crop the raster layer to the bounding box of the UK shapefile
raster_data_uk <- crop(raster_data, uk_bbox)
```

At this point, I get the error:

> Error in .local(x, y, ...) : extents do not overlap

How can I fix it?